# SVN to Git conversion with renamed trunk

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a multi-project SVN repository that I am trying to convert into multiple Git repositories, one per project.

That part I can handle with git-svn and I've found multiple HOWTO-type documents for that, but where I run into trouble is that one of the current projects was created by renaming and merging parts of different projects in SVN multiple times.  In SVN I can see the history of individual files back through the renames/moves, but when I use git-svn and specify the current location of the project's trunk directory, it only converts history up to the point where the layout was changed, I lose all of the older history from when trunk was moved from a different path.

Specifically, my repository's layout used to look like this:

```
/projectA/trunk/src/com/mycompany/projectA/MyClass.java
/projectB/trunk/src/com/mycompany/projectB/OtherClass.java
```

This was converted to:

```
/trunk/projectA/src/com/mycompany/projectA/MyClass.java
/trunk/projectB/src/com/mycompany/projectB/OtherClass.java
```

And then it was renamed and src directories were merged onto a common trunk:

```
/combined-project/trunk/src/com/mycomany/projectA/MyClass.java
/combined-project/trunk/src/com/mycomany/projectB/OtherClass.java
```

So if I run:

```
git svn clone --trunk=/combined-project/trunk
```

Then I get a git repository wih history only going back to the most recent rename.  Does anybody have any advice on how I could get git svn clone to follow trunk back through renames?